# Resizing screen shot image leads to blurred text ios

Tags: ios, uiimage, aspect-ratio

My code:

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

**The first parameter** is image which is screen shot my view controller.

**The second parameter** newSize is actually smaller than the image size which follows the **aspect ratio** also. But the image is looks good but the **text(UILabel) are some what blur**.

How can i solve this any idea?

Comment: change 0.0 to 1.0 . hope this work for you.

Comment: Have you got the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming newSize is in points:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale);
```